# Xamarin.IOS - Google-Maps-Utils-Binding AOT Error GMCluster.GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator:.ctor()

Tags: xamarin.ios, aot

I'm using this library for Google Maps Clustering on `xamarin.ios`
https://github.com/NateRickard/Google-Maps-Utils-Binding

and have a problem when deploy on device. Work perfectly on iPhone simulator, but when execution comes to the statement

```
var iconGenerator = new GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator();
```

is displayed this error:

> Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'GMCluster.GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator:.ctor ()' while running in
>   aot-only mode. See
>   https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/
>   for more information.

Do you have any idea to resolve this problem?

Thanks.
Luca

Comment: Try Changing the Linker Behaviour in build settings from Link All to Link Framework SDK's Only.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try

Comment: Doesn't work, same error :(